# Question about the remainder term of Euler-Maclaurin formula

Tags: real-analysis

Why does the remainder term of Euler-Maclaurin formula satisfies:$$R_{m,n}=\lim_{n->\infty}R_{m,n}+O{\left(\frac{1}{n^m}\right)}$$

Comment: How is $R_{m,n}$ defined?

Comment: $R_{m,n}=(-1)^{p+1}\int_m^n{f^{(p)}(x)\frac{P_p(x)}{p!}dx}$ @i707107

Comment: I believe it should be
$$R_{m,n}=(-1)^{m}\int_a^n{f^{(m)}(x)\frac{P_{m}(x)}{m!}dx}.$$
I got this from the Wikipedia page for Stirling's approximation, though it is not explicitly stated.